# docker-compose how to pass env variables into file

Tags: docker-compose

Is there any chance to pass variables from docker-compose into `apache.conf` file?
I have Dockerfile with variables

```
ENV APACHE_SERVER_NAME localhost
ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www/html
```

I have apache.conf which I copy into **/etc/apache2/sites-available/** while building image

```
ServerName ${APACHE_SERVER_NAME}
DocumentRoot ${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}
```

I have `docker-compose.yml`

```
environment:
        - APACHE_SERVER_NAME=cms
        - APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
```

When I run `docker-compose`, nothing happened and `apache.conf` in container is unchanged.
Am I completely wrong and is this imposible or am I missing any step or point?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain some little differences among ways to pass environment variables:

**Environment variables for building time and for entrypoint in running time**

- ENV (Dockerfile): Once specified in Dockerfile before building, containers, will have environment variables for entrypoints.
- environment: The same than ENV but for docker-compose.
- `docker run -e VAR=value...` The same than before but for cli.

**Environment variables only for building time**

- ARG (Dockerfile): They won't appear in deployed containers.

**Environment variables accesibled for every container and builds**

- `.env` file defined in your working dir where executes `docker run` or `docker-compose`.
- env_file: section in docker-compose.yml file to define another `.env` file.

As you're trying to define variables for apache conf file, maybe you should try to use apache as entrypoint, or just define them in `.env` file.